# Terminal Bash Error on startup

Tags: macos, terminal

Every time I launch terminal, I keep getting this syntax error.

> ```
> -bash: /Users/Jake/.bash_profile: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
> -bash: /Users/Jake/.bash_profile: line 2: `alias mysql='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql'if which rbenv >
> /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi'
> ```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want that alias just edit your /Users/Jake/.bash_profile and remove or comment that line with a `#` at the begininning . If you do want that alias please post your .bash_profile so we can look at what the error is.

Hope it helps